# Mass spring system, elongation of the spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, spring

Is it possible to calculate the elongation of a spring with only the length of the spring, a spring constant and the mass that is attached to the spring?

Comment: Of course, $F=kx$ where the force is the weight of the mass.

Comment: So if the spring constant is $1.13 N/m$ and my spring is $0.01$ Meter and I attach a mass of $20$ gram $(0.1961330005728 N?)$. The elongation is $0.1961330005728 / 1.13 = +- 0,17$ meter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. Is the temperature constant? We need to know if the spring has any electric or magnetic properties. Is someone touching it and compressing it? Are you doing the experiment on a horizontal table? If vertically, on Earth or Jupiter? Is the mass large enough that it would take the spring out of its Hooke regime? Are you on free fall?

Comment: I just need to simulate a spring in 1D. On earth, the spring has no special properties, nobody is touching anything and the mass is small, so it won't go out of it's Hooke regime and no free fall.

Comment: lemon already wrote $F=k x$. Since $F=m g$, you have $x=(m g) / k$. ;-)

Comment: Although humorous, learners may find your answer misleading :-)